# Numpy piecewise unexpected results

Tags: python, numpy, piecewise

I am trying to define a non continuous function using `numpy.piecewise`:

```
import numpy as np

var = np.array([0.2, 10])
supp = lambda x: -np.sqrt(1 - 1/x**2)
inf = lambda x: 1j*np.sqrt(1/x**2 - 1)

def q1(eta_B):
    return np.piecewise(eta_B, [eta_B > 1, eta_B <= 1],
                        [supp, inf])
```

Using this code, this is what I obtain:

```
>>> supp(var)
array([        nan, -0.99498744])
>>> inf(var)
array([ 0.+4.89897949j, nan       +nanj])
>>> q1(var)
array([ 0.        , -0.99498744])
```

I don't understand what is happening here; I expected `q1(var)` to return `array([0.+4.89897949j , -0.99498744])` !

Any hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `q1(var)` don't you get the following warning?

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Chinchi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 616
    y[cond] = func(vals, *args, **kw)
ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
```

Looking at the docs for [`np.piecewise`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html), we see

> The output is the same shape and type as x

Since you never defined a type for `var` and all its values fit within float, then that's the type it gets.

```
>>> var.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> var = np.array([0.2+0j, 10])
>>> var.dtype
dtype('complex128')
>>> q1(var)
array([ 0.        +4.89897949j, -0.99498744-0.j        ])
```

The best way to fix this is to convert the input to complex type within the function, so that it can work whether you pass int/float/complex and having to worry about the conversion yourself.

```
np.piecewise(eta_B.astype(np.complex128), [eta_B > 1, eta_B <= 1], [supp, inf])
```

Comment: Yeah I figured this out a little bit a after. Thanks ! I voted to close this with duplicate to another question with the same answer.

Comment: @Liris Good catch. I didn't consider searching for a duplicate here.